# Activity is very slow to show when screen is locked and app crash when call requestDismissKeyguard()

Tags: android, react-native

I need for my call video app a screen to show even when screen is locked. I used this very good [tutorial](https://medium.com/@shivanshrajpoot/create-a-react-native-app-which-works-on-lock-screen-android-b127f0177455) to achieve this and it's working, screen wake when user receives a call.

But my problem is that this screen is very slow, it takes 4-5 seconds to turn screen on, it takes 5 seconds to respond when I press a button...

Also I want the Keyguard to be dismissed when I press `imageView` button(bring up the UI so the user can enter their credentials: PIN, password, pattern...) so I used `requestDismissKeyguard` but the app crashes when I call it.

I read that in my case it's better to use a service instead of activity but I don't know how to convert My activity into a service. I'm not very familiar with android development so I don't know where the problem came from.

ReactMethod in ActivityStarterModule.java

```
@ReactMethod
void showActivity(String text) {

Intent myIntent = new Intent((Application)reactContext.getApplicationContext(), BackgroundCallActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("text", text);
        myIntent.putExtras(b);
        ((Application)reactContext.getApplicationContext()).startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

My activity in AndroidManifest

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<activity
        android:name="BackgroundCallActivity"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
/>
...
```

Here's my activity code

```
package com.my_project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.CallSuper;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BackgroundCallActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    @CallSuper
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.background_call_activity);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1){
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
        } else {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = b.getString("text");

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(value);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        final TextView mCustomToast = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                mCustomToast.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                    if( keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked()) {
                        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(BackgroundCallActivity.this, null);
                      } else {
                        ActivityStarterModule.triggerAlert("answer");
                        finish();
                    }

                        return false;
                    }
                });

        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hangup);

                imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        ActivityStarterModule.triggerAlert("reject");
                        finish();

                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Have you any suggestion to remove this delay and to make `requestDismissKeyguard` work it will be great.

Comment: Hey, i dont know if this is going to change something, but i made a module to this functionality. can you try him? `npm install --save https://github.com/willnaoosmit/react-native-keep-awake`. On the README.md it's the instructions. Hope it works!

Comment: If you want to see how it's made, the function who make it all its here: https://github.com/willnaoosmit/react-native-keep-awake/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/corbt/keepawake/KCKeepAwake.java